# $\liminf(x_{n}+y_{n})= x + \liminf(y_{n})$ if $x_{n} \rightarrow x$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

As I'm studying measure theory, I've seen the fact in the title of my post used several times. In particular, it has been used in the proof of Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem. (I, myself, have used this fact when proving result that rely from Fatou's lemma.) To be honest, I don't remember using all of the properties of the limit inferior during undergraduate real analysis. So, I decided to prove it. For whatever reason, I was getting confused. Here's is my attempt.

**Claim:** If $(x_{n})$ is a convergent sequence, say, with limit $x$ and $(y_{n})$ is bounded, $$\liminf(x_{n}+y_{n})= x + \liminf(y_{n})$$

**Attempt:** Put $w_{N} = \inf_{n \geq N} x_{n} + y_{n}$ and $u_{N}= \inf_{n \geq N} y_{n}$ so that $\lim_{N} w_{N} = \liminf (x_{n}+y_{n})$ and $\lim_{N} u_{N} = \liminf (y_{n}).$
Let $\epsilon > 0$. Because $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ there exists $M$ such that $n \geq M$ implies $$-\epsilon < x_{n} - x < \epsilon.$$ So, $x-\epsilon < x_{n}$ for all $n\geq M$. Also, $x + y_{n} -\epsilon < x_{n} +y_{n}$ for all $n\geq M$. It follows that $$x+ u_{M} - \epsilon \leq x + y_{n} -\epsilon < x_{n} +y_{n}$$ for all $n\geq M$ and, therefore, $$x+ u_{M} - \epsilon < w_{M}.$$ Taking the limit as $M \rightarrow \infty$ (*Can I do this?!?*), we get $$x + \liminf(y_{n}) -\epsilon  \leq \liminf(x_{n}+y_{n})$$ and $$x + \liminf(y_{n})  \leq \liminf(x_{n}+y_{n}) + \epsilon.$$ Because $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude $$x + \liminf(y_{n})  \leq \liminf(x_{n}+y_{n}).$$

---

If this direction is correct, I've got the other.

Answer (score 1):

$x_n+y_n\geq x_n + \inf_{n\geq N} y_n$ for all $n\geq N$ so $\inf_{n\geq N} (x_n+y_n) \geq x_n + \inf_{n\geq N} y_n$ for all $n\geq N$ so taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ we get $\inf_{n\geq N} (x_n+y_n) \geq x + \inf_{n\geq N} y_n$, and finally taking $N\rightarrow\infty$ gives us the desired inequality.

You might need $\epsilon$-s for the other direction but you say you have it already.  What you wrote looks fine.  What you did with taking $M\rightarrow\infty$ would make more sense by replacing it with some $m\geq M$ (since $M$ is fixed), then you take $n\geq m$.